# How can i print all row value of to a Document using Draw String in C#

Tags: c#

I have tried this code, but it showing outofrange exception, how can I resolve it, pls help

```
try
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Convert.ToInt32(OrderGV.Rows.Count)-1; i++)
    {
       graphics.DrawString(OrderGV.SelectedRows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString() + "\t" + OrderGV.SelectedRows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString(), new Font("Century", 14, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(startx, starty+200));
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{
   throw;
}
```

***Here OrderGV is a Datagridview.

Comment: Have you tried looping over the SelectedRows count rather than Rows.Count ?

Answer (score 0):

You are looping over all data rows, but your drawing function only uses selected rows which causes an error if not all rows are selected. So the problem is, the Rows array in your loop is bigger than the SelectedRows array. I think the following should work.

```
try
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Convert.ToInt32(OrderGV.Rows.Count)-1; i++)
    {
       graphics.DrawString(OrderGV.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString() + "\t" + OrderGV.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString(), new Font("Century", 14, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(startx, starty+200));
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{
   throw;
}
```

Or the other way around if you only want the selected rows

```
try
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Convert.ToInt32(OrderGV.SelectedRows.Count)-1; i++)
    {
       graphics.DrawString(OrderGV.SelectedRows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString() + "\t" + OrderGV.SelectedRows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString(), new Font("Century", 14, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(startx, starty+200));
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{
   throw;
}
```